# Call recent posts on the layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Imagine i have a blog, and i want a footer or sidebar displaying my 3 most recent posts at any given time.

What is the best way to do this?

I can call `@recent_posts` in every single controller to have them ready for the layout but this doesn't seem like the best way...at all...

```
@recent_posts = Posts.all(:limit => 3)
```

I've been fiddling around with partials, but they do need an instance variable carrying the `@recent_posts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be two parts to your concern: 1) performance, and 2) effort required.  Both are easily addressed.

As Andrei S notes in his answer, the convenience/effort issue is mitigated by using a `before_filter` that calls the method that does the work from the `ApplicationController` class.

The performance issue is only slightly more work.  Instead of the method being

```
def most_recent_posts
  Posts.order(created_at DESC).limit(3)
end
```

instead do this

```
def most_recent_posts
  @most_recent_posts ||= Posts.order(created_at DESC).limit(3)
end
```

which checks the instance variable for nil; if nil, it does the query and assigns the result to the instance variable.

You'll also need a way to update when a new post is added, so perhaps something like

```
def clear_most_recent_posts!
  @most_recent_posts = nil
end
```

and then just call `clear_most_recent_posts!` from the method(s) that modify the table. The `before_filter` will do its work only when needed.

I am sure some more eloquent rubyist has a nicer way of doing this, but this is an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the part where you have your posts in a partial and use it in the general layout of your app.

To load them all in every controller you could do a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController` in which you set your instance variable, which will be available in your partial that gets rendered in the layout

This way you only get to do it once, and it will get done everywhere (of course you could set conditions on the filter and the layout to load them when you need, that's if you don't really need them on every page)